# How to validate a first name via regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a registration page and I need to ask the user for his first name.

I want him to have the option of not capitalizing the first letter but I don't want capital letters inside of his name, and I don't want to allow any non-letter characters as well.

Comment: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: What about `Jean-François`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written this function for your purpose.

```
/**
 * This function checks if first name
 * is valid. Keep in mind this is
 * not the proper solution. It will
 * work only for names written in
 * latin letters.
 * @example
 *   isFirstNameValid('Ivan')
 *   will return true.
 *   isFirstNameValid('IvaN')
 *   will return false.
 * @author Georgi Naumov
 * gonaumov@gmail.com for contacts and
 * suggestions
 **/
const isFirstNameValid = (firstName) => 
  /^[a-zA-z][a-z]+$/.test(firstName)
```

Edit: 
 I have implemented a solution with unicode support for the people with a similar problem in the future. It supports Latin, Hebrew and Cyrillic. If you want to support another cultures you need to provide regexes for them inside cultures hash.

```
const isFirstNameValidWithUnicodeSupport = (firstName, culture = 'LATIN') => {
  const cultures = {
    HEBREW: /^[\u0590-\u05FF]{2,}$/,
    CYRILLIC: /^[\u0410-\u042F\u0430-\u044F][\u0430-\u044F]+$/,
    LATIN: /^[A-Za-z][a-z]+$/,
  };
  return  cultures[culture].test(firstName);
}

This returns true because is valid name in latin
alphabet. 
console.log(isFirstNameValidWithUnicodeSupport('Ivan'));
This returns true because is valid name in cyrillic
alphabet. 
console.log(isFirstNameValidWithUnicodeSupport('Иван', 'CYRILLIC'));
This returns false because is valid name in cyrillic
alphabet but there is a space in the end. 
console.log(isFirstNameValidWithUnicodeSupport('Иван ',  'CYRILLIC'));
This returns true because is valid name in hebrew
alphabet. 
console.log(isFirstNameValidWithUnicodeSupport('אגרת',  'HEBREW'));
This returns false because is valid name in hebrew
but is whole name containing spaces. Not only first name.
console.log(isFirstNameValidWithUnicodeSupport('אגרת בת מחלת',  'HEBREW'));
```

Edit2: 
 Probably better solution is xregexp library if you want to use library for that purpose. 
https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp

Comment: Why do you think a name has at least 2 characters?

Comment: Maybe "al" for example. :) Hebrew doesn't have capital letters - this is the difference which I know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex for matching string characters.

```js
let regex = /^[A-Za-z][a-z]+/g;

let name = "Mark";
let match = regex.exec(name);
if(match && match[0].length === name.length){
  console.log(match[0]); // Mark
}
else{
  console.log("Invalid name");
}

name = "mArk";
match = regex.exec(name);
if(match && match[0].length === name.length){
  console.log(match[0]); 
}
else{
  console.log("Invalid name");
}
```

[To learn more about regex.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: But when the input is 'Name1' the forementioned regex considers it valid, but I don't want this to be the case.

Comment: I misunderstood it a bit, I have updated the answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: `(([a-z]|[A-Z]){1})` should be written `[A-Za-z]`, `{1}` is useless as well as all these capture groups that slow down the process